# How to handle validation messages using selenium rc for c#?

Tags: c#, validation, selenium-rc, message

I want to handle validation messages like "Please enter username" if username field is blank.
Currently I am fetching data from excel sheet and I want to compare the validation message with the row value for column "expected result" and if those two matches put the result as "Pass" in excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with two ways

1) selenium.visible("text")
It will capture the Hidden text and client side messages

2) Try with Getalert()
and .Isalertpresent() after a wait for Alert function

> assertEquals("Please enter username", selenium.getAlert());

OR

> assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Please enter username"));

Link for detailed information : http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp

Comment: I had tried to use selenium.visible("text") but it gives an error message as "'Selenium.Iselenium' does not contain a defination for 'visible' accepting a first argument of type 'Selenium.Iselenium' could be found (are you mising a using directive or an assembly reference)"

Comment: Have you added the Selenium DLL to the project?

I have a basic tutorial available here that should help you through getting started.   http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/tutorials/selenium/selenium_csharp_nunit.htm